# Prove the linearity for CRC

Tags: crc

I know that CRC is a linear function which means CRC(x xor y) = CRC(x) xor CRC(y), but I don't know how to prove this property for CRC.

Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

That is not generally true.  It is only true for CRCs that have the property that a CRC of a string of zeros is always zero.  (That property is easily derived from your equation.)  Most CRCs have pre and post processing, for which one of the purposes of the pre-processing is to assure that that is *not* the case.  You wouldn't want a check algorithm to not be able to distinguish how many zeros there are in a string of zeros.  Similarly, for such a check algorithm you could prepend any number of zeros to a message with no change in the check value.

A "pure" CRC without pre or post processing *does* have the linearity property you define.  This can be seen by looking at what CRC register implementation does with a single bit and how that changes if you invert the bit.  The one bit rolled off of one end of the register, which is determined by the bit you fed into the other end, determines if the register is exclusive-ored with the polynomial word.  If that bit is inverted, that reverses that decision.  So the exclusive-or of those two CRCs is the polynomial word.  If you feed a single one bit out to that end of the register initialized as zero (this is where the no pre-processing is important), you get the polynomial word.  So the CRC of the exclusive-or of the messages is equal to the exclusive-or of the CRCs.  This is then extended to all bits by applying this finding one bit at a time.